# Write r GET query from data provided

Tags: r, api, url, httr

I have JSON data about R request that i need to write with necessary url, access token, parameters and other things, which must be included in httr query. I got it from getpostman item. Here it is:

```
        {
            "name": "GET /tablesbyquery",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "hnjP4YUF-woR0jhUyJIByeOI_q8jF99jK5WlQ", #fake for example
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://somesource.os-pub.com/tables/tablesbyquery?timePeriod=actual&sort=utdDate,asc&query=&isNotEmptyStatus=false&size=20&page=0&providerId=",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "somesource",
                        "os-pub",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "tables",
                        "tablesbyquery"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "timePeriod",
                            "value": "actual"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "sort",
                            "value": "utdDate,asc"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "query",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "isNotEmptyStatus",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "size",
                            "value": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "providerId",
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
```

I need to write R request query to GET necessary data. How it should look like? Im new in url and i have written this part:

```
url <- "http://somesource.os-pub.com/tables/tablesbyquery?timePeriod=actual&sort=utdDate,asc&query=&isNotEmptyStatus=false&size=20&page=0&providerId="

access_token <- "hnjP4YUF-woR0jhUyJIByeOI_q8jF99jK5WlQ"

res <- GET(url, access_token)
content(res, "parsed")
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors? What is the output of `res`?

Comment: @mhh it gives ```$timestamp
[1] 1.5916e+12
 
$status
[1] 500
 
$error
[1] "Internal Server Error"
 
$message
[1] "No message available"
 
$path
[1] "/tables/tablesbyquery" ```